# net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE deploying heroku app to google domains

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, heroku, dns, cname

I have a heroku app set up at http://employbl.herokuapp.com. I own the employbl.com domain on google domain so I would like employbl.com and www.employbl.com to render the website hosted on heroku.

I added the domain to the heroku config:

```
$ heroku domains:add www.employbl.com
 ▸    heroku-cli: update available from 6.13.13 to 6.14.27-c74500f
Adding www.employbl.com to ⬢ employbl... done
 ▸    Configure your app's DNS provider to point to the DNS Target
 ▸    www.employbl.com.herokudns.com.
 ▸    For help, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

The domain www.employbl.com has been enqueued for addition
 ▸    Run heroku domains:wait 'www.employbl.com' to wait for
 ▸    completion
$ host www.employbl.com
www.employbl.com is an alias for www.employbl.com.herokudns.com.
www.employbl.com.herokudns.com has address 23.21.222.104
www.employbl.com.herokudns.com has address 23.23.118.21
www.employbl.com.herokudns.com has address 23.23.151.35
www.employbl.com.herokudns.com has address 174.129.214.98
www.employbl.com.herokudns.com has address 23.21.245.33
www.employbl.com.herokudns.com has address 23.21.55.239
www.employbl.com.herokudns.com has address 54.225.70.24
www.employbl.com.herokudns.com has address 23.21.228.1
```

In the Google Domains console I created a custom resource record and a synthetic record as outlined [here](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6346300?hl=en) and specified in the [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)

[image]

[image]

The application renders fine at employbl.herokuapp.com but when I navigate to www.employbl.com the HTML renders for my application but the Javascripts and CSS do not. It is a Vue.js app so nothing renders in the browser. In the console I get an error:

```
GET https://www.employbl.com/css/app.css net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
www.employbl.com/:37 
GET https://www.employbl.com/js/app.js net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

How can I configure google domains and heroku to play nice together and render my heroku hosted application on the www.employbl.com URL?

I am running OSX sierra and the latest Chrome version

Answer (score 0):

It turns out in my app service provider (Laravel) I was forcing HTTPS for all requests. Once i turned that off it rendered properly